# Desktop icon for mounted NAS volume changes location and it annoys me

Tags: macos, finder, desktop, nas

Question relates to the desktop icon for a mounted networked drive.

MacOS 10.14.6 - Seagate NAS SMB - Computer stays on and is set to never sleep.  Airport Extreme.

I mount the drive/volume and I get an icon.  I put the icon in a specific location and then at some point it moves to first available location on desktop.  How can I make it stay where I put it?  It's not a huge thing but it is annoying.

Every other icon on my desktop stays where I put it (Time Capsule drives, Time Machine USB drive, internal drive, files, folders, etc.)

My hunch is that the connection to the drive times out and then automatically reconnects, during this process the icon goes away (connection to drive ends) and then comes back and goes to first open location (connection to drive is re-established).

Any ideas on how to keep my NAS drive/volume icon where I put it?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .DS_Store file on the desktop could help. Keep in mind that all icon positions are getting lost:

- Open the Terminal.app in /Applications/Utilities
- enter "rm ~/Desktop/.DS_Store" without quotes and hit enter
- Relaunch the Finder

  - Press and hold the <kbd>opt</kbd> key
  - Right-Click or Control-Click on Finder in the Dock (while still holding down the Option key)
  - Select **Relaunch**

Also make sure there is some empty space around your wished position (2-3 icons wide).